# Search by ID on tinysong.com

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, request

i am trying to create an interaction between tinysong and grooveshark in my own application

Now what i really want is to be able to question a ID of a song on tinysong, to se if it exists or not.

if you search for a song on tinysong, the webadress shows you the ID of the song like this

http://tinysong.com/#/share/aa/25062638

where 25062638 is the ID..

I tryed to create a httpwebrequest and then scrape the result to see if the ID is valid and what the name is, but its an Ajax call so the result does not show up on the httpwebrequest..

I have also looked into firebug (which im not very good at) and i see there that
there is a post request to tinysong.com?s=sh with the postdata

q%5B%5D=25062638&q%5B%5D=search&q%5B%5D=aa

where first one is ID second is static search, and latter is searchtext, which i typed (aa)

i have tryed to recreate the post request to the path with the postdata above but it returns the footer??!

This is the code i wrote:

```
  string html = string.Empty;


  string requestString = @"http://tinysong.com?s=sh";
  HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);

  ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
  string postData = "q%5B%5D=4&q%5B%5D=search&q%5B%5D=aa";

  byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

  HttpWReq.Method = "POST";
  HttpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  HttpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

  Stream newStream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream();
  newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

  newStream.Close();


  // Create the web request  


  // Get response  
  using (HttpWebResponse response = HttpWReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
  {
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    // Console application output  
   html = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

I am definately missing something here, so any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a bit heavy. Let me suggest you a simplification using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "q[]", "25062638" },
                { "q[]", "search" },
                { "q[]", "aa" },
            };
            var result = client.UploadValues("http://tinysong.com?s=sh", values);
            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var obj = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);

            // there's also obj["html"] in the returned JSON
            Console.WriteLine(obj["message"]);

            // TODO: we have fetched the HTML, now you could scrape it in order to
            // extract the information you are interested in. You could use
            // an Html parser such as Html Agility Pack for this task:
            // http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, your right, that helped alot, but i have the same issue, if you look at what the HTML contains, its only part of the bottom half of the page for some reason, and not the actual "song data" that i want to scrape...

Comment: AHHHHHHHH i just realized that there is an HTML part of the json response and also a message part, that has the part i need, i just replaced      obj["html"] with obj["message"] and i got what i want, thanks alot Darin!!!!

Comment: @user1204023, I have updated my answer to reflect this. If this post helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.